# Trying to design with highChart but colors are not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I am trying to create a Chart Like this sample

[**SampleChart**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/)

My code for creating the chart looks like this

```
function makeGraph(title, x_axis, Target, Achieved) {
       $('#weekly').highcharts({
           chart: {
               type: 'line'
           },
           title: {
               text: title
           },
           subtitle: {
               text: 'Source: ide-global.com'
           },
           xAxis: {
               categories: x_axis
           },
           yAxis: {
               title: {
                   text: 'Money'
               }
           },
           plotOptions: {
               line: {
                   dataLabels: {
                       enabled: true
                   },
                   enableMouseTracking: false
               }
           },
           series: [{
               name: 'Target',
               data: Target
           }, {
               name: 'Achieved',
               data: Achieved
           }]
       });
   }
```

and My JsFiddle is here

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n2bfwgzz/)

Can any one let me know why the line in the chart is not coming up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are feeding strings to the data object.
If you console log your Target variable you will get this output:

```
["Week 1", 111111.11, 0, "Week 2", 111111.11, 0, "Week 3", 111111.11, 0, "Week 4", 111111.11, 200000, "Week 5", 111111.11, 0, "Week 6", 111111.11, 0, "Week 7", 111111.11, 0, "Week 8", 111111.11, 0, "Week 9", 111111.11, 200000]
```

HighChart can not handle string within the data object.

If you change this: `mWeek = "Week " + i;` to this: `mWeek = i;` then it will work.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n2bfwgzz/2/)